# What are the details of Poisson process?

Tags: probability, statistics, poisson-distribution

How could we identify a distribution that follows Poisson distribution given we only have qualitative knowledge about the distribution?

Moreover, what is the relationship between the form of the probability mass function of Poisson distribution and an event that is described by Poisson process?

I understand that the pmf of Poisson can be derived from limiting n in the pmf of binomial distribution  to infinity given the probability of one event = expected value/n 
But what is the relationship between this treatment and the Poisson process?

Comment: A Poisson process $N(\cdot)$ with parameter $\lambda$ is a continuous-time stochastic process. It is a counting process, it counts the number of events: $N(t)$ is the number of events in time interval $[0,t]$. The distribution of $N(t)$ is a Poisson distribution with parameter $\lambda t$.

Comment: In practice, of your samples from a counting process are somewhat unimodal, the way to check for Poissianity is by finding the dispersion ratio $D=\frac{\sigma^2}\mu$. It is $1$ for Poisson, $<1$ is there is repulsion/underdispersion (more like binomial) and $>1$ if there is attraction/overdispertion (more like negative binomial).